# Compiling c++ file from java

Tags: java, c++

My problem regards to compiling c++ file within java. I have tried execution of c#, it is fine. 
This extract code for compiling c#

```
ProcessBuilder launcher = new ProcessBuilder("gmcs","HelloWorld.cs");`
```

However, my code for c++

```
ProcessBuilder launcher =new ProcessBuilder("g++", "HelloWorld.cpp -o HelloWorld");
```

returns error=2, No such file or directory
To indicate path I used
`launcher.directory(new File(path))` 
in both of cases

Comment: Is this a C++ library that you're using?

Comment: print out that path somewhere in your code and see where it is.

Comment: The 1st thing I would think to check is whether g++ is in your PATH so that it can be called from wherever this java program is, and also whether the HelloWorld.cpp is in the same directory as your java app.  Next I would check that I am using ProcessBuilder properly.

Comment: @TonyTheLion No, it is java library

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to provide arguments separately:

```
ProcessBuilder launcher =
    new ProcessBuilder("g++", "HelloWorld.cpp", "-o", "HelloWorld");
```

Otherwise the whole argument string is passed as *one* argument to the `g++` executable, and `g++` tries to find a file named `HelloWorld.cpp\ -o\ HelloWorld` (using escaped spaces as you would on a Linux terminal).

[See the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#ProcessBuilder(java.lang.String...)) for details on the usage.

Comment: That solved me the compilation problem and created HelloWorld file. Then I am using launcher.command("g++","./HelloWorld") to run it, but this return me null. is it right use of method? or there are should be another way?

Comment: @Aidos That’s now how you run executables. Why are you trying to pass it to the compiler (`g++`) again? Just run it directly, that’ll work.